# creating generator function from ordinary function

Tags: python, generator

I'm reading about generators on http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/
(which is very fine, informative article even if it's a ppt slide)

It has the following section about `creating geneators`

Any single-argument function is easy to turn
into a generator function

```
def generate(func):
 def gen_func(s):
   for item in s:
     yield func(item)
 return gen_func
```

• Example:

```
gen_sqrt = generate(math.sqrt)
for x in gen_sqrt(range(100)):
 print(x)
```

I don't see the point of this slide. (it's on 114p of the slide)

Isn't it just `(math.sqrt(e) for e in range(100))`

What is he acomplishing with `generate` function?

Comment: it is accomplishing a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). The difference is that the `for` statement will execute `math.sqrt(1)` then `print(x)` in this order. If it were not a generator function it would first execute `math.sqrt` on all the values in the `range(100)` then it would start iterating and printing

Comment: @LucasWieloch I am sorry but `for x in: (math.sqrt(e) for e in range(100)): print(x)` will also alternately calculate the sqrt for one value and print that value.

Comment: Yes indeed, because that is a generator expression, which is equivalent to the code in the function in the question. I was had mistaken it with a list comprehension, thanks @RonaldAaronson

Comment: Not equivalent to the code, but the gen_sqrt instance at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of such **higher-order** functions is to allow multiple inputs to a function to be chosen at different **times/places**:

```
def filter_lines(f,filt):
  with open(f) as f:
    for l in f:
      print(' '.join(list(filt(map(float,l.split())))))
```

This can accept any kind of iterable-transformer as `filt`, like

```
def ints(it):
  for f in it:
    if f==int(f): yield f
```

or the *result* of `generate`:

```
filter_lines("…",ints)
filter_lines("…",list)  # the identity: print all
filter_lines("…",generate(math.sqrt))
filter_lines("…",generate(abs))
```

Therefore we can see that `generate` **transforms** a function of one element into a function of iterables of elements.  (This is what is meant by “turn into a generator function”.)  We can go one further:

```
import functools
filter_lines("…",functools.partial(map,math.sqrt))
```

from which we can conclude that `generate` itself is equivalent to `functools.partial(functools.partial,map)`.  Applying `partial` twice like that *splits* a parameter list in two, changing a normal function *into* a higher-order function.